# Trying to create SQL instance in Google Cloud - Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to follow instructions for deploying Django Application with PostgreSQL on Google Cloud on the following link:
https://cloud.google.com/python/django/kubernetes-engine.
But I am running in some sort of error when i try to start SQL proxy using connectionName.

Here is the command I am running:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="poised-diagram-202622:us-east1:agent-technologies-db"=tcp:5432
```

And here is the error i get after i run it:

[image]

Any thoughts whats going on? And is it important that I accidentally messed up the time zone, why is setting up correct time zone important?

*** UPDATE ***

When i do not use quotes I am getting the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According [to syntax  in documentation,](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) you don`t need the quotes.

Just run the command without quotes:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=poised-diagram-202622:us-east1:agent-technologies-db=tcp:5432
```

**Update:**

Ok, let's start from the beginning.
First, try to remove and download *cloud_sql_proxy*  again:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy  && chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
```

Then try to run proxy:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=$(gcloud sql instances describe $Your-Instance-ID | grep connectionName | awk '{print $2}')=tcp5432
```

Please don't forget to replace $Your-Instance-ID with your SQL Instance ID.

Comment: I have updated the answer, checked it and it works for me